# ios 7 : Can anyone suggest me to achieve news feed type scrolling?

Tags: ios

I am working with kind of social media application. Here I have to achieve one task like news feeding in other social media apps (e.g) Facebook, Twitter.

Please provide me the best way to use scroll view effectively. It should scroll up and down and I might need lazy loading for better user experience

Thanks in advance

Comment: UI is one thing, what about the data structure? Is it viable to keep posts in core data? See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590889/what-is-the-best-possible-data-structure-for-a-news-feed-listing-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

I created something similar, using UITableView. To avoid heavy network usage and long loading times, I load 10 posts into the table. Then when the user scrolls to the 3rd-to-last post, it loads another 10 into the table so by the time the user has reached the bottom of the original 10 posts, another 10 is there waiting.

Its a nice fluid method and is how Facebook and twitter achieve the continuous scrolling of news feeds.

All the methods you need are readily available in the stock iOS framework too so no battling 3rd party code and their included bugs!

Comment: Hi rob,what we have to do to load next 10  post?am working with web-service,my feeds are coming from server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UITableView`. Here you can represent each news feed as tableview cell.

For lazy loading see [apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

For creating a custom view for table view cell [see this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use UITableView / UICollectionView to present your data. 
For loading, you should have a look at AFNetworking 2, easy framework with lots of extensions for lazy image loading and asynchronus requests.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Hope this helps.

Have a look at AFNetworking Getting Started how to install AFNetworking via CocoaPod to your project.

So, your ViewController.m

```
// Import relevant Headers
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "MyTableViewCell.h" // Custom TableViewCell
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray; // Array to store JSON - results
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self parseData];
}

- (void) parseData
{
    [self clearResults];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?amgArtistId=468749,5723&entity=song&limit=5&sort=recent" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (responseObject)
        {
            [self handleJson:responseObject];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error %@", error);
        }
    }];

}

- (void) handleJson:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self.dataArray = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) clearResults
{
    self.dataArray = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - TableViewDatasource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *dataDict = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.artistLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"artistName"];
    [cell.thumbImageView cancelImageRequestOperation];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataDict objectForKey:@"artworkUrl100"]];

        // replace placeholderimage with something like [UIImage imageNamed:@"superPlaceholder.png"]
    [cell.thumbImageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage new]];


    return cell;

}
```

Small sample :)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro!!...sadly I don't have much knowledge in lazy image and asynchoronus requests. It would be great you share more info here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UITableView` for that. Create table with custom tableViewCell. You search for the tutorial to create custom `UITableViewCell` with autolayout. iOS provides cashing for tableView implicitly. You should also implement extra cache architecture if you get table rows more then 100.

Comment: Cache the model of your table data using coreData or you can also save in local files. Now load only those portion of that model that are near to whatever the visible index of the table. Like if you have 400 rows the in chat-table then you can save it, now visible cell is last row then you can load last 100 rows into your controller. If user scrolls up and visible cell is index-299 the you load 100 more rows.

Comment: You can also search in stackoverflow for this issue